# MySQL date to PHP DateTime conversion in Symfony2.8-Form

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, doctrine, symfony-2.8

I have a Symfony entity, storing a birthday as follows:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @Gedmo\Versioned
 * @ORM\Column(name="birthday", type="date", nullable=true)
 */
protected $birthday;
```

In MySQL, the birthday is stored as date type, correspondingly. Now, to edit the entity, I'm using a form with a Symfony DateType field for the birthday:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
        ...
        ->add('birthday', DateType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy',
                'attr'=> [
                        'style'=>'',
                ],
        ])
        ...
    ;
}
```

Interestingly, when a birthday stored in the database is a date before Fri, 13 Dec 1901, there appears a wrong date in the form (actually the date one day before). To find out what happens, I changed the format attribute in the form builder to:

```
                'format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss z',
```

and for example if the date is '26.02.1825' it shows '25.02.1825 23:53:28 GMT+0:53:28' in the form field, which looks like it is using a very strange timezone. So, there must be a problem when the MySQL date entry is converted to a DateTime object in PHP by Doctrine, I guess?

As workaround, I added 60 minutes to the converted value (in the getter of the property), but there must be a proper way to handle this. Can somebody help me here?

I'm sure, this has been an issue before, but I really couldn't find any similar questions...

Versions:

- PHP 7.0.27
- Symfony 2.8
- Doctine 1.6

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to produce the error on a lower code level:

```
$timestamp = -4570909200;
$dateTime = new \DateTime();
$dateTime->setTimestamp($timestamp);
print($dateTime->format('d.m.Y H:i:s').'<br>');
$formatter = new \IntlDateFormatter(\Locale::getDefault(), \IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM, \IntlDateFormatter::NONE, 'Europe/Berlin', \IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN, 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss (z)');
$formatter->setLenient(false);
$formatted = $formatter->format($timestamp);
print($formatted);
```

This produces the following output:

```
26.02.1825 00:00:00
25.02.1825 23:53:28 (GMT+0:53:28)
```

TimeZones like 'Europe/London' or 'Europe/Zurich' produce different but similarly odd results. Maybe, one shouldn't use these special TimeZones, but rather 'CET'?

I finally also found a similar post, giving an answer:

[PHP IntlDateFormatter wrong date/time conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45227012/php-intldateformatter-wrong-date-time-conversion)